# What is wrong with this call of a php file in a onchange

Tags: php, html

```
mainTwo.php:

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Setlist</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php require 'provsetlist.php'; ?>
<? include("combo.php"); ?>

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="crlist.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

combo.php

```
<?php

echo '<select id="tunelist" name="tunelist" onchange="Window.location=provsetlist.php">'; 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'setlist', 'music');
$query = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['Database'].'">'.$row['Database'].'</option>';
}
echo '</Select>'
?>
```

This throws a ReferenceError:  provsetlist is not defined

I've looked a bunch of examples and tutorials but have not been able to figure this one out.    I'm assuming that I need to define provsetlist.php but where and how?

Comment: That's because provsetlist hasn't been declared in the code you posted.

Comment: Do you have a php file named "provesetlist.php" in that directory?

Comment: yes there is a file named provesetlist.php

Answer (score 0):

```
onchange="window.location.href = './provsetlist.php';"
```

Comment: i think the require works. The onchange fails because it is not referencing the href correctly, as you can see. Anyway, thanks for your intervention, but I'm sure the OP will not forget to tell me whether i'm wrong

Comment: the echo is actually creating the select combo, and when the user changes the selection it goes to that page. But it crashes instead because of the bug I corrected

Comment: No Dice....  Thanks for the suggestion though.  I also tried combining from combo.php into the mainTwo.html instead of a separate file without any luck.